# can not find field matching field

Tags: java, if-statement, try-catch

my problem is that the first option that collects the data from the user is not connected to the second option found in the if statement (both in bold) . Does anyone have any advice for this?

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please select from the following options:");
System.out.println("1. Enter new Policy");
System.out.println("2. Display summary of policies");
System.out.println("3. Display summary of policies for selected month");
System.out.println("4. Find and display Policy");
System.out.println("0. Exit");

try {
    **int option** = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Error : program closing");
    System.exit(0);
}

if **(option == 1)** {
    System.out.println("Please enter full name: ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();

    while (name.length() >= 21) {
        System.out.print("Name is invalid, please re enter:");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: Read up on variable scope.

Comment: Thank you, helped alot! wouldn't have know to read up about that! not sure whether it was the best option, but just declared option at the start! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it , Modify to fit your own specifications.

```
public static void Options_() {

   select_option();// Here you invoking the list of options available 

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       int number = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (number == 1) {
         //Do something here        

   } else 

        if (number == 2) {
        // Do Something Else        

  }
       //and So on
  }
      public static void select_option() {
      System.out.println("Please select from the following options:");
      System.out.println("1. Enter new Policy");
      System.out.println("2. Display summary of policies");
      System.out.println("3. Display summary of policies for selected month");
      System.out.println("4. Find and display Policy");
      System.out.println("0. Exit");
  }
```